# HTML5 elements CSS & Javascript interaction in IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, html

I am experiencing some issues developing with html5 elements (NAV,SECTION,ARTICLE, etc) under IE8 and below. Simply said I cannot seem to do anything with these elements in javascript or css.

Is there a workaround for this or do I have to convert my entire layout to DIV's again?

Thank you

NOTE:

It seems that this only goes for elements that are added after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Comment: html5shiv only seems to add support for the elements, I still can't seem to access them with Javascript or CSS.

Comment: They should be stylable once you use the shiv. Try making sure to include it before any other JS/CSS

Comment: The problem was on elements added dynamically after the page was loaded. The solution was to use innerShiv along with html5shiv (which I was already using). Nevertheless I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the script downloaded at http://modernizr.com. You can access everything with JS and CSS.

Comment: I'm reading over modernizer but cant get a clear image of what it does, it seems to give me easy access to conditions, which means I'd have to develop apps from the ground up with modernizer in mind. How does this help me with my existing layout? Can I include it and it automatically addresses some of these issues I am having?

Comment: yes. just include it and it does all the magic for you. also, you could provide some code and we could help you with some of your issues.

Comment: Thanks Jason, adding modernizr made no difference for me. Possibly because it has the same limitation as html5shiv; it doesn't process dynamically added elements. I found a plugin called innershiv that will hopefully help me out with this.

Comment: @naatan you are doing something wrong then. it absolutely "processes" dynamically added elements because the whole trick that it performs makes all elements work, regardless of their current or future existence. believe me, i (and my whole company) use modernizr in every project we do and we have to support down to ie6 sometimes.

Comment: Is there anything I should be doing besides including the script then? Cause it made no difference when I tested it.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted you (I upvoted) though modernizr doesn't actually help me with my problem. I suppose you need to be set up properly to be able to utilize it's power.